# How can I batch-compress DNG files in my Lightroom library?

Tags: lightroom-3, dng

I shoot with my Pentax K10d in the DNG format. The camera produces the files in an uncompressed format. I would like to save some disk space by compressing all in a batch process too in Lightroom.

Can I compress all files in my lightroom library at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Attila Acs](http://attilaacs.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/compress-your-native-pentax-dng-photos-after-import-into-lightroom/):

You can compress new DNGs:

```
if I import them using the Lightroom “convert to DNG” command, 
they are compressed
```

You can also compress DNGs already in your Lightroom database:

```
Select the photos in your catalog and choose
“Metadata -> Update DNG Previews & Metadata”
```

Answer (score 2):

[The Lightroom Queen](http://Library%20menu%20%3E%20Convert%20Photos%20to%20DNG) explains how to make Lightroom apply lossy or lossless DNG compression to raw files (including DNGs) that are in your photo library:

1. Select the images. (This means LR can only do this one folder at a time.)
2. Go to **Library menu** > **Convert Photos to DNG...** [not a memorable command name for this purpose]
3. In the dialog, pick:

   - **Only convert RAW files** [that includes DNGs]
   - **Delete originals after successful conversion**
   - Pick lossy or lossless compression as desired
   - *Not* "Embed Original RAW File".

Note: This [Adobe forum thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/352701) explains what "Update DNG Preview and Metadata" does:

1. It does *not* compress the image files.
2. Maybe takes hours.
3. Updates the preview that's embedded in the DNG so other programs (that don't process Lightroom's non-destructive edit list) can get at least a version of the edited image.
4. Updates the metadata stored in the DNG file, although it's unclear from this thread if/when that includes keywords, ratings, color labels, and the edit list.

Comment: Note that the original question here isn't asking about lossy compression, at least not necessarily. Due to CPU limitations, the K10D could only save completely uncompressed DNG files — not even lossless compression. Newer Pentax cameras do not have this limitation.

Comment: @mattdm Thanks, I missed that point. So the original question is how to compress DNGs in the photo library, either lossy or lossless. I'll update that step. I found this question looking to further compress library photos applying lossless DNG compression during import, but the accepted answer didn't work.